# rails3 i18n accepts_nested_attributes_for how-to translate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, internationalization, nested-attributes, rails-i18n

I'm using Rails 3.2.6 and this is an example case:

```
class Man < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :eyes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :eyes
end
class Eye < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :man
  validates_inclusion_of :color, in: { %w[brown green blue] }
end
```

Views (in HAML):

```
= form_for @man do |f|
  - if @man.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      %h2= t 'errors.messages.record_invalid', count: @man.errors.count
      %ul
        - @man.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          %li= msg

  = f.fields_for(:eyes) do |b|
    .field
      = b.label :color
      = b.text_field :color

  .actions
    = f.submit :submit
```

it.yml:

```
it:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      customer:
        eyes: Occhi
      customer/eyes:
        color: Colore
  errors:
    models:
      man/eyes:
        attributes:
          color:
            inclusion: non valido
```

However the label of color is not translated (but it is with 'actviterecord.attributes.eye.color'), the attribute in the error message is only "Occhi" and the rest is `errors.model.eyes.attributes.color.inclusion` instead of `errors.models.man/eyes.attributes.color.inclusion`

The error message is the `errors.model.man.attributes.eyes.inclusion`, but how can I differentiate it? It should be something like "Occhi Colore non valido" instead of "Occhi non valido"

Answer (score 7):

Try this out:

```
it:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      # set the name used in nested attribute error messages
      customer/eyes:
        color: Occhi Colore
  errors:
    models:
      # change the error message for eye color not included in the list
      eye:
        attributes:
          color:
            inclusion: non valido
    messages:
      # change the inclusion message globally
      inclusion: non valido
  helpers:
    label:
      # set the label used by form builder for labels
      man[eyes_attributes]:
        color: Occhi Colore
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I just lost an hour trying to figure out where ActiveRecord was looking for that damn key.

Comment: @JoelCogen My favorite thing to identify the specific keys is a monkey patch on I18n::Backend::Simple#lookup that logs the requested keys.